# String concatenation in javascript outputs bad result

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I want to create random usernames. 
I use a list names and firstnames from a file and get one from each files randomly.

```
var nameList= fs.readFileSync("random-name/names.txt").toString().split("\n");
var name = nameList[Math.ceil(Math.random()*nameList.length)];

var firstnameList= fs.readFileSync("random-name/first-names.txt").toString().split("\n");
var firstname= firstnameList[Math.ceil(Math.random()*firstnameList.length)];
```

The problem appears when I want to concatenate them:

```
console.log( name);
console.log( firstname);
console.log( firstname+"-"+name);
```

outputs:

```
Brant
Jesselyn
-Brantyn
```

There is obviously no problem if I set the variable `name` and `firstname` statically.

Comment: Maybe there is a CR character at the end of firstname? Try to print the string lengths...

Comment: You want `Math.floor` instead of `Math.ceil`

Comment: you are also right but that is not the current problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted yourself, remove `\r` from the input, or alternatively split on `\r?\n`.

Other notes:

- Don't repeat yourself.
- Your "random item" calculation is wrong, you should be using `floor`, not `ceil`.

How about:

```
function getLines(filename) {
    return fs.readFileSync(filename).toString().split(/\r?\n/);
}
Array.prototype.getRandomItem = function () {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
};
```

and

```
var nameList = getLines("random-name/names.txt");
var name = nameList.getRandomItem();

var firstnameList = getLines("random-name/first-names.txt");
var firstname = firstnameList.getRandomItem();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because I splitted the file content with "\n", and there was still "\r" at the end of each names and firstnames.